# Delete a specific node in a linked list

Tags: c

Need to search for the specific node and then and delete, but for some reason this code doesn't end up changing the node that needs to be deleted. cmdNum is just the position of the node not a value in the struct.

```
CmdNode *deleteCommand(CmdNode *head, int cmdNum) {
 

    CmdNode *temp1 = NULL;
    CmdNode *temp2 = NULL;
    
    temp1 = head;
    temp2 = head -> next;
    
    
    int pos = 0;
    
    while (temp2!= NULL){  
        
        if(cmdNum == pos){
            
            
            temp1 ->next = temp2->next;
            free(temp2);
            
            
            return head;
        }   
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        pos++;
    }
   

  return head;
}
```

Comment: This code does not account for a null head or if head is to be deleted. Need a [mcve] to see what isn’t working.

Comment: It doesn't account for when there is only 1 item in the list and that's the one to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For starters,  temp2 is initialized to NULL in a list with only 1 item.

You aren't accounting for deleting the "head" of the list (pos == 0) being deleted.

And you aren't accounting for an empty list either where head is initially null.  This would surely crash at `temp2 = head->next`.

Here's some quick fixes:

```
CmdNode *temp1 = NULL;  // "previous"
CmdNode *temp2 = head;  // "current"

int pos = 0;

while (temp2!= NULL){  
    
    if(cmdNum == pos){
        
        if (temp1 != NULL) {
            temp1->next = temp2->next;  // previous now links to next
        } else {
            head = temp2->next;         // head was deleted, new head
        }

        free(temp2);
        return head;
    }

    // advance both pointers
    temp1 = temp2;
    temp2 = temp2->next;
    pos++;
}
return head; // not found, just return the head of the unchanged list
```

Comment: For some reason this dosen't work it won't delete the actual node.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: My psychic powers suggest you need to be comparing `cmdNum == temp2->value` or something similar instead of with `cmdNum == pos`.  That's typically how you search for a specific node in a linked list.

Comment: Well there's code in place that show's  us if the functions works as intended or not, also cmdNum dosen't refer to a value in the struct

Comment: And how am I supposed to know that?  Seriously, show us the entire picture, not just the scope of where you think the bug is.